# Limit to HTTPRequest parameter size between Flex/BlazeDS and Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, blazeds

We have a web app with a Flex front end making requests to our Spring/Tomcat back end through BlazeDS.

I noticed when the data for a parameter we send in the request is over a certain size (something like 1.5M), it simply doesn't show up as a parameter in the request in our servlet.  We've verified that the value is populated in the request on the Flex side.  When the parameter is below that size, it comes through fine.

Has anyone seen this?

Is this happening on the BlazeDS side or the Tomcat side?

Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add maxPostSize in Connector configuration in server.xml. For example,

```
<Connector port="80"               
 ...
 maxPostSize="4097152" />
```

Comment: My boss said "Just make sure they don't send that much output", so now I don't need to solve the problem at all, but your answer certainly addressed it, so I'm giving you the checkmark.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the logging verbosity of BlazeDS in the services-config.xml file:

```
<target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Debug">
```

That should show you what the server is receiving.